# Вывести с помощью js информацию

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!

Интересует такой вопрос:
Как с помощью js можно вывести любую информацию, но чтобы эта информация летела из JS, а не просто показать, например, div у которого был класс display:none;?
Я, например, вывожу, как раз таким способом:

```
<input type="text" class="input-number">
<p style="display:none;" id="elem">Привет! Меня показывают и скрывают!</p>
```

JS:

```
$('.input-number').change(function() {
   $("#elem").fadeIn('slow');
   setTimeout("$('#elem').fadeOut();", 2000);
});
```

А вот пример - [ссылка](https://jsfiddle.net/5h1q4gb8/11/)

Но выводится это путём добавления div на сайте с классом display:none;.
Так не очень хотелось бы. Можно как-то, чтобы например это генерировал JS?
Примерно так:

```
var tekst = '<p style="position:fixed;top:20px;right:20px;">Привет! Меня показывают и скрывают!</p>';
```

Т.е. записать информацию в переменную и выводить её точно также по изменению значения в поле input.
По этому поводу информации не нашёл.

Можно, конечно, так - [ссылка](https://jsfiddle.net/fgbsxbb8/1/), но опять же надо иметь в верстке скрытый div.

```
<input type="text" class="input-number">
<div id="elem" style="display:none;"></div>
```

JS:

```
$('.input-number').change(function() {
   var tekst = '<p id="elem2" style="position:fixed;top:20px;right:20px;">Привет! Меня показывают и скрывают:)</p>';
   $('#elem').html(tekst).fadeIn(); 
   setTimeout("$('#elem').fadeOut();", 2000);
});
```

Надеюсь на Вашу помощь :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавляйте Ваш элемент к `body`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var msg = $('<p id="msg">Привет! Меня показывают и скрывают:)</p>');
  $('body').append(msg);
  
  $('.input-number').change(function() {
    msg.fadeIn();
    setTimeout(function() {
      msg.fadeOut();
    }, 2000);
  });
});
```

```css
#msg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input-number"/>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Отлично!

Comment: @Дмитрий Если мой ответ решил Вашу проблему, отметьте его как правильный

Comment: Да, конечно:) Если будет у Вас время, посмотрите, пожалуйста, ещё один вопрос у меня - [ссылка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/626521/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83)