# Добавить количество того товара, который добавляется в корзину

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как по клику на кнопку "В корзину" конкретного товара - брать у него же количество товара, которое ввёл пользователь?

Сейчас у меня выводится с помощью `alert()` количество товара всегда одного и того же товара, не зависимо на какой кликаешь.

Вот пример - [ссылка](https://jsfiddle.net/8kvj0oL9/6/)

*Update:*

Почему, если в `<div class="price">` вложить еще один `div` `<div class="price"><div class="qwerty"><input class="qty" ...` и затем при обращении к `parseInt($(this).closest('.qwerty').find('.qty').val(), 10);` не работает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не задавайте одинаковые `id` разным элементам:

```
qty = parseInt($(this).closest('.price').find('.qty').val(), 10);
```

Ну и: `<input class="qty" ...`. То же - для `id="mot"`.

*Update:*

Потому что `".qwerty"` не находится в цепочке родителей `".add-to-cart"` - http://api.jquery.com/closest/