# Привязать количество товара

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!

При добавлении товара в корзину, у пользователя имеется возможность задавать произвольное кол-во товара перед добавлением.

Мне же нужно следующее: по клику на кнопку "В корзину" конкретного товара - брать у него же количество товара, которое ввёл пользователь.

В моем случае кол-во товара добавляется всегда одного и того же товара, не зависимо на какой кликнул товар. Проверяю я это с помощью `alert()`. В примере все показано. Посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как возможно решить эту проблему.

```js
$('.add-to-cart').on('click', function(e) {
  var that = $(this),
    shows = parseInt(that.attr("data-show"), 10),
    add = that.attr("data-text"),
    qty = parseInt($('#qty').val(), 10);
  alert(qty);
  if (shows == 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
    that.attr("data-show", "1");
    that.text(add);
    that.closest('.catalog-tovarov').find('#mot').show();
  }
});
```

```css
.catalog-tovarov {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0 20px 11px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 230px;
  padding: 1%;
  transition: 0.4s 0.2s ease;
  background: #cfcfcf;
}

.catalog-tovarov:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 9px 0 #CECECE;
}

.price {
  margin-top: 120px;
}

#mot {
  display: none;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="catalog-tovarov">
    <div id="mot"><img width="30px" src="http://sparkysite.ru/small/check/check03/scheck264.png" /></div>
     <div class="price">
        <input id="qty" type="text" name="quant" value="3" />
        <span>444 руб.</span><br/>
        <a class="add-to-cart" data-price="10000" data-show="0" data-text="Перейти в корзину" href="#">В корзину</a>
    </div> 
 </div>
 <div class="catalog-tovarov">
     <div id="mot">
        <img width="30px" src="http://sparkysite.ru/small/check/check03/scheck264.png" />
    </div>
     <div class="price">
       <input id="qty" type="text" name="quant" value="2" />
        <span>444 руб.</span><br/>
        <a class="add-to-cart" data-price="10000" data-show="0" data-text="Перейти в корзину" href="#">В корзину</a>
    </div> 
 </div>
 <div class="catalog-tovarov">
    <div id="mot">
        <img width="30px" src="http://sparkysite.ru/small/check/check03/scheck264.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="price">
        <input id="qty" type="text" name="quant" value="6" />
        <span>444 руб.</span><br/>
        <a class="add-to-cart" data-price="10000" data-show="0" data-text="Перейти в корзину" href="#">В корзину</a>
    </div>   
 </div>
```

Comment: Не задавайте одинаковые `id` разным элементам: `qty = parseInt($(this).closest('.price').find('.qty').val(), 10);`. Ну  и: `<input class="qty" ...`. То же - для `id="mot"`.

Comment: @Igor Спасибо! А почему, если в `<div class="price">` вложить еще один div `<div class="price"><div class="qwerty"><input class="qty" ...` и затем при обращении к `parseInt($(this).closest('.qwerty').find('.qty').val(), 10);` не работает?

Comment: @Igor Пример по [ссылке](https://jsfiddle.net/2g4wa2tv/1/) У меня верстка на самом деле такая:)

Comment: потому что ".qwerty" не находится в цепочке родителей ".add-to-cart" https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: @Igor Предложите свой ответ, то что написали первым комментарием. Отмечу, как правильный.

Comment: Этот вопрос закрыли - ответить нельзя. Но я ответил на дубликат: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/626521

Answer (score 1):

Первое - не используйте одинаковые id на странице, вместо этого используйте классы.

Второе - у вас ни как не обозначалось, в каком же блоке искать количество, в вашем случае можно делать .siblings(), но это не рекомендуется, т.к. тогда слишком большая зависимость от верстки, лучше найти начало блока и в нем нужный элемент, я сделал так, чтобы изменять ваш код поменьше.

Третье, я исправлять не стал, но к data не нужно делать доступ через attr.

```js
$('.add-to-cart').on('click', function(e) {
  var that = $(this),
    shows = parseInt(that.attr("data-show"), 10),
    add = that.attr("data-text"),
    qty = parseInt(that.siblings('.qty').val(), 10);
  alert(qty);
  if (shows == 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
    that.attr("data-show", "1");
    that.text(add);
    that.closest('.catalog-tovarov').find('.mot').show();
  }
});
```

```css
.catalog-tovarov {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0 20px 11px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 230px;
  padding: 1%;
  transition: 0.4s 0.2s ease;
  background: #cfcfcf;
}

.catalog-tovarov:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 9px 0 #CECECE;
}

.price {
  margin-top: 120px;
}

.mot {
  display: none;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="catalog-tovarov">
    <div class="mot"><img width="30px" src="http://sparkysite.ru/small/check/check03/scheck264.png" /></div>
     <div class="price">
        <input class="qty" type="text" name="quant" value="3" />
        <span>444 руб.</span><br/>
        <a class="add-to-cart" data-price="10000" data-show="0" data-text="Перейти в корзину" href="#">В корзину</a>
    </div> 
 </div>
 <div class="catalog-tovarov">
     <div class="mot">
        <img width="30px" src="http://sparkysite.ru/small/check/check03/scheck264.png" />
    </div>
     <div class="price">
       <input class="qty" type="text" name="quant" value="2" />
        <span>444 руб.</span><br/>
        <a class="add-to-cart" data-price="10000" data-show="0" data-text="Перейти в корзину" href="#">В корзину</a>
    </div> 
 </div>
 <div class="catalog-tovarov">
    <div class="mot">
        <img width="30px" src="http://sparkysite.ru/small/check/check03/scheck264.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="price">
        <input class="qty" type="text" name="quant" value="6" />
        <span>444 руб.</span><br/>
        <a class="add-to-cart" data-price="10000" data-show="0" data-text="Перейти в корзину" href="#">В корзину</a>
    </div>   
 </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, позже попробую у себя в проекте. Скажите, пожалуйста, почему нельзя использовать одинаковые id на странице? И почему к data не нужно делать доступ через attr?